How to dynamically access tables across multiple databases using Entity Framework Core?
In my company, we have a system with the following structure:

Moldable hosts: servers are defined by their IP addresses

Moldable databases: each database is created based on a country code

Company-specific tables: each company has its own set of tables (the same structure for all companies), which are named using the company code. Some table names also include the year


Currently, we use dynamic stored procedures to query a SQL Server database. The process involves using a centralized COMPANY table (shared among all companies) to retrieve the necessary server, database, company code, and year information. This is then used to construct a dynamic SQL query.
Here's an example of our current approach:
USE dbUnified
GO
DECLARE
     @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    ,@idCompany INT
    ,@serverERP VARCHAR(50)
    ,@baseERP VARCHAR(50)
    ,@codeERP VARCHAR(50)
    ,@yearERP VARCHAR(50)

SELECT 
     @serverERP = C.serverERP 
    ,@baseERP = C.baseERP
    ,@codeERP = C.codeERP
    ,@yearERP = C.yearERP
FROM
    COMPANY C
WHERE
    idCompany = @idCompany

-- Dynamic SQL for tables without year
SET @SQL = '
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        ['+@serverERP+'].['+@baseERP+'].[dbo].[TABLENAME'+@codeERP+'00]
'

-- Dynamic SQL for tables with year
SET @SQL = '
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        ['+@serverERP+'].['+@baseERP+'].[dbo].[TABLENAME'+@codeERP+@yearERP+']
'

EXEC SP_ExecuteSQL @SQL

We are now transitioning to Entity Framework Core, and I’m unsure how to replicate this dynamic behavior using C#.
Here are the challenges I'm facing:

Dynamic table and column mapping
The database table names are not intuitive. For example:

Table names: PL03{CompanyCode}00 or SupplyerManager{CompanyCode}{YearERP}.
Column names: PL03001, PL03002, etc.

I'd like to map these table and column names to meaningful names in C#. For example:

Table PL03{CompanyCode}00 → Invoice
Column PL03001 → supplierCode, PL03002 → invoiceNumber, etc.


Dynamic database selection
My current DbContext only interacts with fixed tables (e.g., dbUnified). I need to dynamically connect to other databases and tables programmatically.

Expected Usage
I'd like a single DbContext that allows me to query data dynamically, like this:
companyInfoDbContext.Invoice.FirstOrDefault(x => x.supplierCode == "123" && x.invoiceNumber == "321");
// or
companyInfoDbContext.Supplier.FirstOrDefault(x => x.supplierCode == "123");



What I've tried so far

I've created a DbContext for dbUnified, which works fine for static tables

However, I haven't figured out how to handle multiple databases programmatically


Question
How can I implement a solution in EF Core that allows:

Dynamic database and table selection.
Mapping table/column names to meaningful C# models and properties.

Any guidance or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!


I'm afraid transitioning to EF Core with such requirements was not a good idea (had to research all these "challenges" in advance) since EF Core is exclusively for static mapping of data models to single database schema.

Look at Multi-tenancy, Alternating between multiple models, Advanced table mapping

You will need a DbContext for each database. Probably not the best approach.

The static parts can be mapped in EF. Even the company-specific tables could be mapped if the structure is really equal in each company and only table names differ. That would require tables names that the EF model reads at runtime. The variable part should be handled by something like Dapper. That said, the question in its current form is too broad. You should supply a minimal example that represents the problem and that others can use to experiment with.

We use EF core in other company projects, at the moment this project that I'm trying to implement in this way is in .NET framework, which doesn't work with several technologies and architectures like docker for example, so I'm trying to use a company standard first before passing to other options. Not to mention it's a great opportunity to learn new things. - Ivan Stoev

I'll take a look at it, If I succeed I will mark it as an answer- Alexander Petrov

You will need to have DbContext options with predefined Model for each tenant. Possible but needs efforts, it should be similar to this my answer when instead of changing schema you should define for each tenant connection string and correct table names. And I also think that EF Core is not suitable for this task.

I will add an example of tables in databases to represent my problem in a replicable way, but what I do today was represented by the code I put in the part about the database - Gert Arnold

You said that you think EF Core is not suitable to work in this way, is there any other option that I can use? - Svyatoslav Danyli

Do you need this only for queries? Which ORM generated such schema?

Everything that a ORM does, read, write, update and delete data from the database, the only catch is that it needs to work with various databases and table names and on the surface work like EF core to keep company standards. At the moment in this system, it depends on another software that uses this database, that's why the names for tables and columns are so bad - Svyatoslav Danyli

Then adopt solution for multitenancy that I have mentioned. Configure Model for each database dynamically. Well, it is possible, but needs efforts.

In my company we long ago stopped using EF... and went back to Dapper + Stored Procedures. We found that EF added too much complexity for the benefits it provided.

@DaleK, EF Core was once like a child, experiencing its own growing pains. It's a far cry from the current version, which, when used correctly, delivers exceptional performance.

Since you already have a "database", the "data base first" approach has EF generate your entities for you. I would expect "one" dbContext" per "company" (at least); even if they are "the same". EF generates "entities" in the form of "partial" classes. The fact that one can "extend" partial classes, means you can "add" any naming / redirection, etc. that you want. It's a "mapper"; physical to logical. How you "interpret" it; or"re-interpret" it is only limited by imagination.

Create SYNONYMs so that EF can work with consistent set of names, and your DBs can have whatever they like for table names

Alternately, generate your context code programmatically and use annotations or builder mappings to point EF to whatever name of table is relevant for your consistent c# code

I managed to make it work in my project, thanks to the example provided by Svyatoslav Danyliv, the references shared by Alexander Petrov, and the help from the people in the comments. Thank you all!
Basically, what I needed to do was create a DbContext builder. This builder receives the company to be queried, constructs the connection string, and dynamically defines the table names to be queried (only the mapped ones, of course). In the end, it returns a DbContext referencing only the tables and database for that specific company.
I created a demo project for anyone who wants to test it out. If possible, feel free to submit pull requests with suggestions for improvements. I’ve never used EF Core in this way before, so there’s a chance it’s not implemented in the best way.
